# Java Programming Method Overloading

Tags: algorithm, computability, oop, java

First time posting here sorry about the format.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        float x, y, z;
          System.out.println("Enter two integers to calculate their sum ");
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          x = in.nextFloat();
          y = in.nextFloat();
          z = x + y;
          System.out.println("Sum of entered integers = "+z);
       }




public static void main1(String args[]) {

    int x, y, z;
      System.out.println("Enter two integers to calculate their sum ");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      x = in.nextInt();
      y = in.nextInt();
      z = x + y;
      System.out.println("Sum of entered integers = "+z);
   }

}
```

---

I need help method overloading on letting my program add numbers with int and floating point for example 
4 and 5 = 9

4.0 and 5.0 = 9.0

but as of now my output is only giving me floating point value even if I just input number with int values.

Comment: how do you want to differentiate if user entered int or float?

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` method stores the inputs and the sum in `float` variables, which is why the sum is also float.

Your other method `main1`, which accepts `int` inputs is not used.

If you want overloaded methods, one for `int`s and one for `float`s, you should have a single `main` method that would call the overloaded method (let's call it sum).

```
public static int sum (int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}

public static float sum (float x, float y)
{
    return x+y;
}
```

However, the method that will be called depends on the arguments that you pass to it. Therefore, if you use `nextFloat` to get the input, the `sum (float x,float y)` method will always be called, even if the user inputs integers.

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
  float x, y, z;
  System.out.println("Enter two integers to calculate their sum ");
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  x = in.nextFloat();
  y = in.nextFloat();
  z = sum (x,y); // this will always call sum (float x, float y)
  System.out.println("Sum of entered integers = "+z);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run the class main function is executed first(if you dont have static block etc) by JVM and as you din't call `main1()` only `main()` is executed giving you float value.

> Note:**Overloading** means two methods or more with the same name but with
>   different parameters

**But you have different method name with same arguments.**

So to achieve overloading use same name for both functions and with different type or number of arguments.

In order to overload `main()` you can overload it but when you run class by `java ClassName` it will call only the main method with String array arguments `main(String[] arg)`.You can overload `main()`  further with your code by calling it with different arguments.

[Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)